# C# Linq Lambda Conteo de elementos

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Tengo un problema con LINQ y es que no se como resolver el problema de contar los elementos con ciertas condiciones.

Explicación:

Tengo el siguiente conjunto de elementos en un objeto de tipo `List<Dispositivo> _devices`

```
{
    root: [{
            dispositivo: 413,
            variables: [{
                    name: "Ignition",
                    value: false,
                    type: "Boolean",
                    unit: "boolean",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:06:36.0000000Z"
                }, {
                    name: "Speed",
                    value: 0,
                    type: "Double",
                    unit: "M/S",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:06:54.0000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            dispositivo: 418,
            variables: [{
                    name: "Ignition",
                    value: true,
                    type: "Boolean",
                    unit: "boolean",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:08:19.0000000Z"
                }, {
                    name: "Speed",
                    value: 19.3888888888889,
                    type: "Double",
                    unit: "M/S",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:08:19.0000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            dispositivo: 419,
            variables: [{
                    name: "Ignition",
                    value: true,
                    type: "Boolean",
                    unit: "boolean",
                    utc: "2021-03-22T20:20:22.0000000Z"
                },{
                    name: "Speed",
                    value: 0,
                    type: "Double",
                    unit: "M/S",
                    utc: "2021-05-04T16:19:06.0000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

escribí  el siguiente código para intentar contar las variables de esten en la siguiente condicion:

Contar los dispositivos cuya variable "Ignition" este con valor "true" and cuya variable "Speed" sea mayor o igual a 5.

Escribí esto pero no me funciona me da errores en la edición.

```
var sobrevelocidad = _devices.Count(d => d.variables.Where(s => s.name == "Speed" && s.value.ToString() == "true"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien supera mas sobre LINQ y LAMBDA que me pueda dar una mano con eso.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil marcarla como aceptada y/o dale un voto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es mas o memos la que ha puesto rmrgnzlz pero con una variación.

```
var count = _devices.Count(d => d.variables.Any(v => v.name == "Ignition" && v.value == "true") && d.variables.Any(v => v.name == "Speed" && v.value >= 5));
```

Son 2 condiciones, y no puedes poner las 2 en el mismo any ya que un device tiene varias variables y las condiciones son que tengan una variable con un valor y otra con otro valor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **Linq** para resolver tu problema:

```
var cont = (from d in devices 
            from v in d.Variables
            where v.Ignition == true && v.Speed >= 5
            select v).Count();
```

Esta consulta **Linq** recorre la **lista de dispositivos**, y por cada dispositivo recorre su **lista de variables** y filtra mediante la **cláusula where** todos los elementos que cumplen con la condición dada, y una vez hecho este filtro se aplica el **método Count**, para que devuelva la cantidad de elementos que cumplen las condiciones dadas.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Ocurre que la estructura de devices es diferente.

es algo como esto,

class Variables 
{
 string name,
 object value,
 type string,
 unit string,
 utc  string
}

class Dispositivos
{
 int device ,
 Lis<Variables> variables 
}

Y la consulta seria valida si estuviera utilizando un solo elemento **List<Variables> ** en este caso lo que se recorre es un **List<devices>** y la variable "Variables" esta contenida en cada elemento de **devices**

Comment: Gracias Bro, me fue de mucha ayuda!!

Comment: @JoséDonoso, hola si la respuesta te fue útil podrías marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
var sobrevelocidad = _devices.Count(d => d.variables.Any(s => s.name == "Speed" && s.value.ToString() == "true"));
```

Recuerda que el método **where** retorna una lista, mientras que el método **any** retorna un *bool*.